# Custom token generation using TokenHelper in struts2 java application

Tags: java, struts2, token

In struts2, there is a TokenHelper class which generates a random token using the below code.

```
private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();
public static String generateGUID() {
     return new BigInteger(165, RANDOM).toString(36).toUpperCase();
}
```

For some reason this token is not secure enough. So we need to use SecureRandom class to generate the token. How can I do this in my application? Localizing the TokenHelper class won't help. Please suggest.

Comment: What do you mean by `Localizing the TokenHelper class`? It's not locale aware.

Comment: I meant writing a new class which extends TokenHelper inside our project. But there is no option to include it anywhere in struts xml(i think)

Comment: @DivyaRose Just update Struts.

Comment: After 11/21/2014, Struts uses `SecureRandom`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Struts 2.3.20 or newer where Struts uses `SecureRandom`.

Comment: Is there any way to do it other than struts upgrade?

Comment: I think creating `/org/apache/struts2/util/` path in your app's source folder and then copying https://github.com/apache/struts/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/struts2/util/TokenHelper.java there  should work.